# Linq to Xml: reading from XML null reference exception

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to use `Xml.Linq` to read from an Xml I previously created by `Xml.Linq`. This is how XML looks like:

```
 <ItemsCollection>
  <Item>
    <ItemName>Computer</ItemName>
    <ItemDescription>Computer's description</ItemDescription>
    <ItemCategory>Electronics</ItemCategory>
    <ItemPrice>2499.99</ItemPrice>
  </Item>
</ItemsCollection>
```

Code responsible for parsing those elements into `Item` class objects is this:

```
 var res = from myItem in xdoc.Root.Elements("Item")
                      select new Item((string)myItem.Element("ItemName"), (string)myItem.Element("ItemDescription"),
                      (Category)Enum.Parse(typeof(Category), (string)myItem.Element("ItemCategory")), (double)myItem.Element("Price"));
```

When being executed, linq expression throws NullReferenceException.

Comment: can you also post definition of `Category`?

Comment: Try : (double?).  If double is null you need the question mark.

Comment: @jdweng (double?) cast is incorrect - "cannot convert `double?` to `double`"

Comment: @[Lei Yang] `Category` is just enum type with three values: `Clothes`, `Electronics` and `Food`

Comment: The the class Item constructor parameter list must also be made double?.

Comment: Your query should be for the element `ItemPrice`, not `Price`. There is no element called `Price`, hence the result is `null`.